# Python - Convert json list to a data frame

Tags: python, json, dataframe

I have a list that contains nested json data and I would like to convert everything that is in the 'data:' tag into a data frame. The list contains multiple records inside the

```
emptylist = [{'data': {'id': 7478290440, 'version': 0, 'bonus_opening_balance': 7.4, 'cash_opening_balance': 30.83, 'external_round_id': '8997958938', 'game_id': 29788, 'game_session_id': 144418070, 'last_updated_at': '2023-06-29T14:03:03Z', 'started_at': '2023-06-29T14:03:03Z', 'status': 0, 'cash_stake': 0, 'cash_win': 0, 'bonus_stake': 0, 'bonus_win': 0}, 'metadata': {'timestamp': '2023-06-29T12:03:07.699650Z', 'record-type': 'data', 'operation': 'insert', 'partition-key-type': 'schema-table', 'schema-name': 'revolve', 'table-name': 'game_round', 'transaction-id': 103414267563647}}, {'data': {'id': 7478290359, 'version': 2, 'bonus_opening_balance': 0, 'cash_opening_balance': 11.13, 'ended_at': '2023-06-29T14:03:03Z', 'external_round_id': '8997958480', 'game_id': 16210, 'game_session_id': 144418025, 'last_updated_at': '2023-06-29T14:03:03Z', 'started_at': '2023-06-29T14:02:58Z', 'status': 1, 'cash_stake': 0.2, 'cash_win': 0.03, 'bonus_stake': 0, 'bonus_win': 0}, 'metadata': {'timestamp': '2023-06-29T12:03:07.708711Z', 'record-type': 'data', 'operation': 'update', 'partition-key-type': 'schema-table', 'schema-name': 'revolve', 'table-name': 'game_round', 'transaction-id': 103414267564722}}, {'data': {'id': 7478290440, 'version': 1, 'bonus_opening_balance': 7.4, 'cash_opening_balance': 30.83, 'external_round_id': '8997958938', 'game_id': 29788, 'game_session_id': 144418070, 'last_updated_at': '2023-06-29T14:03:03Z', 'started_at': '2023-06-29T14:03:03Z', 'status': 0, 'cash_stake': 0.2, 'cash_win': 0, 'bonus_stake': 0, 'bonus_win': 0}, 'metadata': {'timestamp': '2023-06-29T12:03:07.717096Z', 'record-type': 'data', 'operation': 'update', 'partition-key-type': 'schema-table', 'schema-name': 'revolve', 'table-name': 'game_round', 'transaction-id': 103414267565254}}]
print(emptylist)
```

Comment: I tried 

`
df = pd.json_normalize(emptylist)
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

`

but this includes everything inside the metadata tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a DataFrame from the list and use `apply` on the `"data"` series to make it a DataFrame:

```
pd.DataFrame(emptylist)["data"].apply(pd.Series)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import pandas as pd
emptylist = [{'data': ... }]
data_list = [record['data'] for record in emptylist]
df = pd.DataFrame(data_list)
print(df)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).